# Erreur in Installation PUGXMultiUserBundle

Tags: symfony, pugxmultiuserbundle

I want to install   PUGXMultiUserBundle. I followed  the documentation of PUGXMultiUserBundle:https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md 
I have downloaded the PUGXMultiUserBundle with success and I continued  Creating my Entities. I created an entity User:

```
<?php
namespace Register\UserBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"societe" = "Societe", "chercheur" = "Chercheur"})
     *
     */
  abstract class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
    /**
         * @var string $image
         * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
         */
        protected $image;
         public $file;
      protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            return 'image';
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir()."/".$this->getId()."/";
        }
        public function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadDir().$this->getId()."/".'/'.$this->image;
        }
        public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/".'/'.$this->image;
        }
         public function getAbsolutePath1()
        {
            return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().$this->image;
        }
     /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist
         * @ORM\PreUpdate
         */
        public function preUpload()
        {
             if (null !== $this->file) {
                // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
                $this->image = uniqid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
              }
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostPersist
         * @ORM\PostUpdate
         */
        public function upload()
        {
             if (null === $this->file) {
                return;
              }
              // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
              // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
              // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
              $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image);
              unset($this->file);
        }
    /**
         * @ORM\PreRemove()
         */
        public function storeFilenameForRemove()
        {
            $this->filenameForRemove = $this->getAbsolutePath1();
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostRemove()
         */
        public function removeUpload()
        {
            if ($this->filenameForRemove) {
                unlink($this->filenameForRemove);
            }
        }

    }
```

and the other Entity: societe:

```
<?php
namespace Register\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="societe")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Register\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Register\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class Societe extends User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
   /**
     * @var string $adressemail
     */
    protected $adressemail;
    /**
     * @var string $namesociete
     */
    protected $namesociete;
}
```

an finally the last Entity chercheur:

```
 <?php
    namespace Register\UserBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     * @ORM\Table(name="chercheur")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Register\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Register\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
     */
    class Chercheur extends User
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
       /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         * @var string
         */
        protected $region;
        /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         * @var string
         */
        protected $firstname;
    }
```

The problem is when I want to generate my entities after : `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Register`, a error message  appeared in console:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>     Class "Register" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
>   doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
>   .

Can someone help me to fix this problem and Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is : `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Register.`  ? if not please edit your question